# Resize stardoc fences will not work in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, fences, stardock

I have installed fences from stardock on my Windows 7 machine, however, I can not get the fences to resize. I know what is supposed to work, but no amount of click and dragging will do the trick.

Anyone else had a similar problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> no amount of click and dragging will
>   do the trick.

If the Fences are locked, you can 'click and drag' until the cows come home. :)

Right-click on a Fence, select **View** from the context menu and uncheck **Lock Fences**.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try running fences in compatibility mode for Windows Vista.